# Validation control not firing on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, formview

I'm using a `FormView` control to allow users to insert rows to the database. I want to validate these input fields, and as such have added a regular expression validation helper. Here's the markup:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <p>
        Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$" ControlToValidate="NameTextBox" ID="NameTextBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must be alphanumeric characters and spaces"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </p>
    <p>
        Location:
        <asp:TextBox ID="LocationTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>' />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
    </p>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

However, when I click `InsertButton` the page refreshes and I get an error from SQL Server saying it can't insert a NULL value, the validator isn't getting used at all.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the user entered no text and the database does not allow null values.

A `RegularExpressionValidator` will not validate empty controls. So you need to provide also a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

> The validation will not fail if the input control is empty. Use the
>   RequiredFieldValidator control to make the field required.

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_regularexpvalidator.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not much info here, but I'll venture a guess:

Check to make sure you don't have anything happening OnLoad that's blanking things out.  If you do have an OnLoad make sure it only fires when IsPostback is false.